# Validation of a MIME type

Tags: java, mime, apache-tika

I want to write a method that receives the data to create a file, e.g.,

```
public File createFile(String fileName, String mimeType, byte[] contents)
```

In that method, how can I check that the value of `mimeType` is acceptable? JDK 7 `javax.activation.MimeType` class and [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org) do not seem to provide such a check method or any list of known mime types.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: What's "acceptable" in this context? Anyone can invent a new file format and create a corresponding MIME type. For example, I could define a binary file format for SO posts and metadata and send such a file to you with the mimeType "application/StackOverflowQuestionData". If you accept that is your decision alone. In most practical contexts the solution is either to accept a fixed list of MIME types, or not bother with it.

Comment: You can get all Mime Types that Apache Tika knows about with [TikaConfig.getMediaTypeRegistry()](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/config/TikaConfig.html#getMediaTypeRegistry--)[.getTypes()](https://tika.apache.org/1.24/api/org/apache/tika/mime/MediaTypeRegistry.html#getTypes--) but I'm not sure that is what you actually want...

Comment: @l4mpi Thanks for your answer. By "acceptable", I meant "standard", "usual".

Comment: @Abra Thanks, but I needed a plain list of MIME types

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, `TikaConfig.getMediaTypeRegistry().getTypes()` is exactly what I needed!